# Create a script to catch links on a webpage with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, try-catch, html

I have to catch all the links of the topics in this page: https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/

I've tried with this script:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = (urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

but it prints all the links of the page, and not just the links of the topics as I'd like to. could you suggest me the fast way to do it? I'm still a newbie, and i've started learning python recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

url= 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/'
soup= BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
```

Then find the links with

```
soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'})
```

Comment: thanks for answer but if I follow your method, and I print (soup) it gives me the source of the page, and not the links of topics :\

Comment: This gives you tag objects. To get the urls as strings, use `[tag.get('href') for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'})`

Comment: ok. now i got the links I wanted, but they are inside html codes. `<a class="PreviewTooltip" data-previewurl="threads/dichvusocks-us-23h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455661/preview" href="threads/dichvusocks-us-23h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455661/" title="">[DICHVUSOCKS.US] 23h10 PM UPDATE 24/24- Good Socks</a>` but it is a good step forward!  :)

Comment: man, thanks to you, I solved. this is the final code: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url= 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/'
soup= BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'}):
    print(tag.get('href'))`
thanks again